# redirect all external requests to the prod equivalent of the server url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to say:

For all IP Addresses that are not within the 110.140 or 110.10 ranges. If they are trying to access a URL that begins with "stage." then redirect them to the same URL but remove the "stage." portion of the string from the url.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(110\.(140|10)) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\. [NC]
RewriteRule stage\.(.*) https://$1 [R=301,L]
```

When using just the last two lines in [made with love htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) the last line fails (is not met).  I haven't tested the code on a server.

**Update:**

After reading the Apache RewriteRule Directive details, I realized that the RewriteRule Directive does not search the HTTP_HOST, only the things after that.  Therefore this approach will not work.  Does anyone have an approach that will work?

Comment: What is an example URL that you're trying to redirect?

Comment: If the URL is https://stage.mydomain.url I would like to redirect to https://mydomain.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your hostname starts with `stage.` not the URI. You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^110\.(140|10)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: This did work out for me . Sorry for the delayed response.  Thanks!